# How to do signature using stylus and save it as image in Android?

Tags: android, digital-signature, aspen

I want to do signature using stylus and save it as image on my device.I have already develope signature using gestures but now I want to do it using stylus.How can I get this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html).Don't know this the exactly the one which you want
Please visit this and hope this helps.

Comment: thnx..but I am done with this code it not supports spen or stylus.